# Como determinar si existe un nodo en específico en un archivo xml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Necesito saber si existe un nodo en especifico de un archivo xml. Es decir si el determinado nodo existe obtener "true" de lo contrario "false".
Este es el codigo por ahora.

```
XmlDocument xmlArchivo = new XmlDocument();
xmlArchivo.Load(ruta);

if (xmlArchivo.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ListOptiReut").exists == true) //Estoy conciente que la instruccion "exists" no existe, solo pongo como ejemplo de lo que necesito.
{
    //Proceso

}
```

xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el mètodo [XmlNode.SelectSingleNode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=net-5.0) para seleccionar cualquier elemento `ListOptiReut` en tu documento:

```
XmlDocument xmlArchivo = new XmlDocument();
xmlArchivo.Load(ruta);


XmlNode nodeToFind;
XmlElement root = xmlArchivo.DocumentElement;

nodeToFind = root.SelectSingleNode("//ListOptiReut");

if(nodeToFind != null)
  {
       // Existe!
  }
  else
  {
       // No existe.
  }
```

Comment: Excelente me funciono, gracias.

Comment: Que bien Ariel, un saludos!